# Docker is not copying subdirectory into Container

Tags: docker

I have the following directory structure

```
|-Dockerfile
|-README.md
|-angula.json
|-package.json
|-...
|-src
   |-index.html
   |-main.ts
   |-...
   |app
     |-app.component.html
     |...
```

Now I want that everything is copied into a container when it is starting up. For that I put the following content into the Dockerfile:

```
From node:12.15.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/

RUN ["npm","install"]

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 4200/tcp

CMD ["npm", "start", "--", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--poll", "500"]
```

When I now build and run the Dockerfile, I have the following issue, that the directory `src` and all its subdirectories are not copied.

When I run `docker exec -it [container-name] sh` and then type `sh` all files which are in the same directory as Dockerfile are there. However if I then go into the `src` folder it is empty.

I would expect that with the `COPY . /app` I am coping the complete folder and all its sub-directories to the container. Why is this not the case? What am I missing out?

Comment: Do you have .dockerignore next to your Dockerfile? Add `RUN ls -l /app/src` after your COPY command and rebuild your image. Check the output of the docker build command. Do you see the contents of your src directory? Also what is the docker run command that you use to start your container?

Comment: How are you starting the container?  Do you have a `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: @Mihai @David Maze I dont not use an -dockerignore file. I am usting the following comands to build and run the container: 
`sudo docker built -t mean-app` and `sudo docker run -it --rm -p 4200:4200 -v ${pwd}/src:/app/src mean-app`

Comment: You don't need `-v ${pwd}/src:/app/src` since you have already copied everything inside the image.

Comment: @Mihai I know, but I do not want to restart the container everytime I do changes to my code. Or do you think that this is causing the issue?

Comment: Then you can remove `COPY . /app` from the Dockerfile because it doesn't make sense in your scenario. Does this fix your issue?

Comment: ...that produces an image that's not really useful without your local source tree; really all that's left is `FROM node`.  If that's what you're looking at, working with a local Node and leaving Docker out of it will be a much easier development environment.

Comment: This question was not related to angular - please do not tag unnecessarily

Comment: @Mihai `COPY . /app` makes sense, since I need all the files, which are outside the `src` folder. When I am starting the container I am only mounting `src` and not the rest of app like all the packages. Please see my resolution of the issue below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very stupid mistake... When I mounted the `src` directory I used `${pwd}` instead of `$(pwd)`, which lead to the empty folder, eventhough I copied previously.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the src entry from .dockerignore